# ZF controllers redirecting to index controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

I had set up a zend framework project.My index controller working fine. But when i tried to access other controllers, i m getting content of index controller only.
For example when i access user/signup, in url i m getting same user/signup, but it taking actions from index controller only.

Comment: show us some code, please (especially controllers)

Answer (score 0):

check your pluggings. search setController(), setAction() methods in your project. When you use that methods they never change URL. But show content for that.